# Is there a way to select a certain row by number in SQL SELECT Statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get a specific row from a table in SQL, but using the row number. Can anyone help me, please?

I was thinking of something like that:

`select * from table where row = 2;`

Comment: Which dbms are you using, MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no row number unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: Number? According to what?

Comment: @jarlh i'm  using sql server

Comment: then please don't tag it mysql :)

Comment: Where is your table schema??

Comment: You can generate a row number using [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and then select the records where row number is 2.

Comment: What are the columns of this table? Is there a primary key? Do you care about ordering?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `SELECT` statements;

- For `ORACLE` database

  ```
  SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * 
            FROM table_name 
           ORDER BY column_name)
   WHERE rownum = 1;
  ```
- For `MSSQL` database

  ```
  SELECT *
    FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_name) AS row 
             FROM table_name)
   WHERE row = 1
  ```

Comment: You can also use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function for Oracle DB, and you should instead of `rownum` is generated before sorting and not reliable for your current case. Moreover if the ties(*the equal values*) occur for the data, it's even better to use `DENSE_RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()` which returns only one row in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The records in a database table are not ordered. SQL row doesn't have any "Number" in the tables.

If the table has an "ID" or a "number" as a **key** or **unique** attribute, then you are able to select one single row.

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE TableName.UniqueAttributeName = ...;
```

The amount of results depends on the attribute is unique or not.

If the SQL WHERE Clause doesn't use a unique attribute, then you are still able to use the limit, in case of the SQL request would return more rows :

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE AttributeName = ...
LIMIT 1;
```

Attention: Using LIMIT means that may more elements are fitting for the WHERE clause, but the SQL query will return only as much as the LIMIT clause set.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL tables don't have order so you need to add it.

Once you have a column with an order you can use that.  For example

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY FIELD_NAME) AS row_num
  FROM TABLE_NAME
) X
WHERE row_num = 2
```